# Input number field more than 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to set a minimum on a input number field so it's more than 0 but the user can still enter 0.01 for example?

I've tried this but it hasn't worked..

```
<input required="" name="amount" type="text" min="0.01" value="0.00" />
```

Comment: input number field ??  `type="text"`??

Comment: use `type="number"`

Comment: _more than 0_ `value="0.00"` 

Comment: Cheers Fellas! Don't how i didn't spot that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution could be, add an `input` event to your . I'm given an id to that input. If the input less than 0.01 then reset it.

Also to use `step` to control the precision.

Also, a situation could be `input = 0.0111`, so in the else statement we do this: `Math.round(+this.value * 100)/100;` (`+` will force the variable to become number type and use Math.round to get the input rounded to two decimal)

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    if(this.value < 0.01){
      this.value = '';
    } else {
      this.value = Math.round(+this.value * 100)/100;
    }
});
```

```html
<input required="" id="test" name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" value="0.00" />
```

Comment: @Shaun updated to handle a situation which input could be 0.0111 or 0.0199 etc

Answer (score 4):

Use [`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) with [`min="0"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Specifying_minimum_and_maximum_values) (you can also use [`step="0.01"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-step) attribute to limit the increments at which value can be set):

```html
<input required="" name="amount" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.01" />
```

Comment: But you can still enter 0

Comment: @guest you have to use JavaScript for that

Answer (score 0):

In you code `type="text"`
Attribute `min` available for `number`, `range` & `date` types.
Try this:

```
<input required="" name="amount" type="number" min="0.01" value="0.01" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input required="" name="amount" id="amount" type="number" min="0.01" 
value="0.00" onblur="return validate(this);" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
function validate(amount){
    if(parseFloat(amount.value)<=0){
        amount.value = "";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```